# sunjce_provider.jar in jre for standalone javafx application

Tags: ant, javafx-2, netbeans-7

I need to include the sunjce_provider.jar into the JRE for a JavaFX standalone application. The problem I'm having is that I have to do it manually after Netbeans creates the bundle image, but that does not include the file in the msi or exe installers.

Is there an Ant target/task that I can override somehow to copy the file automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using "JavaFX Ant tasks or the JavaFX Packager tool" to package your application, enabling verbose mode may help.  Verbose mode can be enabled by adding the verbose="true" attribute to <fx:deploy> and it should give more insight about what resources are being used.  On Mac, it shows where to place a special shell script file to customize the build.  Oracle JavaFX Doc "6.3.3.1 Preparing Custom Resources" has more information (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGICFDB).

Comment: I'm developing in Windows and I tried that, but I wasn't successful. My workaround is to put a copy element after the deploy element in the -post-jfx-deploy target in build.xml and set the nativeBundles="image" After I NB builds the image, I use Inno Setup to package the app in an exe installer.