# Packaged JavaFX Crypto Error: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 SecretKeyFactory not available

Tags: javafx

When testing locally my app works fine but after packaging the app for native deployment I get the following error:

`java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 SecretKeyFactory not available`

Is there a way to install the [JCE unlimited strength policy](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) in a packaged app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a .jar file to native bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241130/how-to-add-a-jar-file-to-native-bundle)

Comment: You're right, the answer I was looking for was there. Is it best to just delete my question or link to the answer?

Comment: There is nothing you need to do.  It will likely become a [closed question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) as a matter of course.  If you really want to delete it yourself, you can read some [deletion advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), but I don't recommend deletion in this instance.

Comment: are you using proguard ?